# Access session value after closing window in php

Tags: php, session

How is it possible to access a session value after the Browser window was closed in PHP?

Comment: `xampp/tmp` folder normally if you are using xampp or you can see `session_save_path()`

Answer (score 0):

Session variable will expires once a browser is closed. If you still want the session variable you should use cookies for that. Store the session values in cookies and access the cookie whenever you need. set *session.cookie_lifetime* to non-zero so that cookie will not expire. For more details about storing and accessing cookies refer [php cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [php session cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a keep alive:
Ex:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();

//if 100 seconds have passed since creating session delete it. Use math to figure out minutes and hours
if(time() - $_SESSION["timeout"] > 100){ 
    unset($_SESSION["timeout"];
}
```

However this may answer your question but its not always a good option.
Your Server Keeps Sessions In Memory and Too Many Can Cause Your Server To Slow Some.

If you want to keep Information About Login Even After Browser Close Use Cookies

```
setcookie("email-","dummytext",time()-60*60*24*365,str_replace(".","_",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),0);
```

check out `setcookie();`

now to check for said cookie beginning of page

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['email-'.str_replace(".","_",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])]) // checks for cookie email-
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php